# Where is the file civicrm.settings.php in WP?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 4.9.6 and CiviCRM
Where is file `civicrm.settings.php`?
It is not in  `/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm`
It is not in  `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm`

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For versions installed before 4.7, the civicrm.settings.php file should be in **/wp-content/plugins/civicrm** (***not /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm***).  As Pradeep says, for newer versions installed from 4.7, the file should be found in **/wp-content/uploads/civicrm**.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

That sounds weird. The /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/ path is for CiviCRM versions older than 4.7. For a new install you should find it under /wp-content/uploads/civicrm. I hope you are looking in right directory.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in:  /wp-content/upload/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php